# Keep order of re-ordered form list box

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

I have a simple form with a list box, I am using JavaScript that allows the visitor to change the order of the list box values.

I also  have script that selects all the items in the list before submit, my PHP script on the other end receives the list values in an array, but does not keep the user changed order. How can I make the array that the PHP script receives be in the new order?

**Form**

```
   <FORM action="list_test.php"  method="post" name="phonenumbers">
<p>
<SELECT NAME="numbers[]" SIZE="7" MULTIPLE>

    <OPTION VALUE='1'> ME 214-555-1212</option>
    <OPTION VALUE='2'> Alex 214-555-1212</option>
    <OPTION VALUE='3'> fred 214-555-1212</option>
  
</SELECT>

<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="&nbsp;Up&nbsp;" onClick="moveOptionUp(this.form['numbers[]'])">

<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Down" onClick="moveOptionDown(this.form['numbers[]'])">
</p>
<p>SUBMIT
<input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" id="SUBMIT" value="Submit" onClick="go()">
 </p>
</FORM>
```

**Submit script**

```
    function go()
    {
    for(i=0;i<document.forms['phonenumbers'].elements[0].length;i++){
    document.forms['phonenumbers'].elements[0][i].selected=true;  // sections[][i]   
    }
    }
```

Comment: i think you can use javascript to convert the data ( all the items in order ) into json format dynamically and then submit that.

Comment: @janenz  last sentence first paragraph; "How can I make the array that the php script receives be in the new order?"

Comment: @Imran I am not familiar with json, can you elaborate?

Comment: Having trouble converting the data into a json object, they still come  out, out of order.

Comment: Ended up creating a hidden field in the form then when the onlick event fired for the submit button I looped through the listbox using document.getelementbyid and placed the results into the hidden field as a pipe delimited string. then when the form actually submitted, my PHP script placed the data into an Array, which I then easily placed into the mySQL database.

Comment: P.S. I couldn't have done it without you pointing me in the right direction Imran!! I would like to give you credit!